# Removing only one of the 2 public values in the URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an e-commerce system written in Laravel 8. Public directory appears in URL.

The software's URL system is as in the network.

Homepage: `website.com/public/`Category: `website.com/public/category`
Product: `website.com/public/category`

CSS file URL address: `website.com/**public**/themes/themename/**public**/css/style.css`
JS File URL address: `website.com/**public**/themes/themename/**public**/js/app.js`

As you can see, there are **2 public values** in CSS and JS files.

I updated the htaccess file as follows to remove the public value.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#remove public/ from URLs using a redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+/)?public/(\S*) [NC]

#RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L,NE]
#Remove index.php
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

#Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

#Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

However, it also removed the 2nd public value of CSS and JS files. That's why CSS and JS files fail.

How can I keep the 2nd public value constant and remove the first public value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your htaccess file in following way, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. I have also corrected few flags in your other rules too.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# remove public/ from URLs using a redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(themes/themename)/public(/css/app\.css|/js/app\.js)\s  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(themes/themename)/(css/app\.css|/js/app\.js)/?$ $1/public/$2 [NC,L]


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Sorry but some pages access with public value. websitename.com/public/product-name, websitename.com/public/category-name etc. How can I remove this public value too. They must be websitename.com/product-name and websitename.com/category-name

Comment: @sakarya, could you please give samples of urls that will give better understand here. From which url TO which url  info will be helpful, thank you.

Comment: The URL system was website.com/public, website.com/public/category, website.com/public/product. I used the htaccess code in my question to remove the public value and it worked.

However, the CSS file was called website.com/public/themes/themename/public/style.css.

The code I wrote to htaccess also removed the 2nd public value here. So style.css was not loading.

I updated the htaccess as you wrote, but website.com/public and website.com are both working together now.

Comment: @sakarya, this looks to me a new question, request you to please revert back to your original question in this post and open a new question, we could discuss it there. Else it will confuse future readers/users, thank you, we could discuss in new question on this one.

Comment: I've reached my question limit. I can't ask new one.

Comment: @sakarya, oh ok, may be after sometime you could open a new one, I would request you to open new one since it will create lot of confusions, if we keep editing this now, kindly revert your questions changes to old one and we can discuss it in new thread.

Comment: @sakarya, I have updated rules, please check them once and let me know then.